# Actualizar registros duplicados

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Cordial saludos estimados.

Intento realizar una actualización de datos con registros duplicados por su numero de documento, tengo dos tablas: A y B,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tabla A solo tiene el numero de documento de la persona, mientras que la tabla B tiene los datos que quiero pasar a la tabla A respectivamente por su numero de documento que tienen en comun.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar la tabla B tiene un identificador de transacción(idtransaccion) este campo es el verdaderamente importante ya que único e identifica la transacción, pudiendo pasar este a la tabla A me sería fácil hacer los demás datos en A, lo que sucede es que la tabla A al momento de hacer el update lógicamente todos los registros repetidos quedan duplicados con una sola transacción de la tabla B(la ultima transacción), aquí un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así debería quedar realmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota aclaratoria: la tabla B es el ejemplo de una tabla en la cual funciona como logs de transacciones de un sistema que maneja grandes volúmenes de movimientos, es decir solo es una tabla de trazabilidad de ahí que aparece el numero de documentos varias veces y así mismo para otros documentos. Por otro lado en la tabla A (es una tabla temporal que he creado) en la cual he importando los números de documento que necesito cruzar en B

Agradezco de su ayuda de antemano, ojala me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás pidiendo, lo resuelves con un simple:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE B;
INSERT INTO A (documento,fecha,idtransaccion)
SELECT documento,fecha,idtransaccion FROM B;
```

Ahora, la cuestión es cómo has llegado a lo que nos planteas.

- ¿Qué realidad estás modelando?
- ¿Por qué el mismo documento aparece cuatro veces?
- ¿Cómo ha llegado el número de documento cuatro veces a la tabla `A`?

Volcar datos es fácil, modelar la realidad es lo complicado. Danos más detalles y podremos echarte una mano con ello.

Comment: Gracias por responder David.

Comment: Te cuento, la tabla B es el ejemplo de una tabla en la cual funciona como logs de transacciones de un sistema que maneja grandes volúmenes de movimientos, es decir solo es una tabla de trazabilidad de ahí que aparece el numero de documentos varias veces y así mismo para otros documentos.                                                                                                                                  Por otro lado en la tabla A (es una tabla temporal que he creado) en la cual he importando los números de documento que necesito cruzar en B

Comment: Genial, edita la pregunta incluyendo estas aclaraciones, son importantes para entender a dónde quieres llegar. No respondes a mi segunda pregunta: ¿por qué pones 4 veces cada documento en la tabla `A`? Si sabes cuántos documentos hay, también conoces el resto de los datos, ¿no?

Comment: Si, David la razón de poner 4 veces cada documento se debe a que seleccione este caso o este documento, por que es uno de los que más se transacciones tiene (4), existen otros casos donde ese documento solo tiene 2 transacciones en el sistema o  en su defecto solo una

Comment: Para entrar en detalle la tabla A tiene los documentos que ha reportado nuestro cliente por consumos al sistema, donde cada numero de documento tiene su equivalente log(transacción) en la tabla B

Comment: Salvo que tengan un significado muy definido, los valores repetidos no suelen sentarles muy bien a las bases de datos. Si ya tienes esos documentos en un log, ¿para qué los llevas a `A`? Pásalos directamente desde `B` y ya después compruebas que no haya quedado ninguno fuera